# Polylines wont show on google maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, polyline

I'm trying to add a polyline to the google map but the implementation doesn't seem to work, or maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

Below you can see how im creating the polyline and adding it to the set then later on i pass it to the google maps widget to create the polyline, but it just doesnt seem to work, i've cheked and the coordinates are decoding properly and the polyline is properly added to the set

```
var thisDetails = await HelperMethods.getDirectionDetails(
        pickUpLatLng, destinationLatLng);

    Navigator.pop(context);


    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
    List<PointLatLng> results =
        polylinePoints.decodePolyline(thisDetails.encodedPoints);

    polylineCoordinates.clear();

    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      results.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(
          LatLng(point.latitude, point.latitude),
        );
      });


      _polylines.clear();

      setState(() {
        Polyline polyline = Polyline(
            polylineId: PolylineId('polyid'),
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 95, 109, 232),
            points: polylineCoordinates,
            jointType: JointType.round,
            width: 4,
            startCap: Cap.roundCap,
            endCap: Cap.roundCap,
            geodesic: true
        );
        _polylines.add(polyline);
      });

    } else {print('results empty');}
```

Comment: What package are you using to get the directions details?

Comment: I was working directly with the api, after some research and tests i found out that it was the polyline package that wasnt working, i changed it to another package and now its fully working